# Divergence and mass in the Gauss Law

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

By taking a point $P$ inside a sphere with uniform density $\rho$, and integrating the contributions of all the points, we get the expression for the gravity field:

$$\mathbf g = -\frac{4}{3}\pi G\rho \mathbf r$$

Where $\mathbf r$ is the position vector of $P$ with respect to the centre. By definition, the divergence of the field is:

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf g = -4\pi G\rho $

I suppose that this expression is more general, being valid for an arbitrary density distribution and form of the solid. It should relate the divergence of the field and the density at $P$ as happens here.

However, if we suppose a thin (compared with the size of the sphere) tunnel passing through the centre, and $P$ inside this tunnel, the value for the field is very close that stated above, and tends to be practically the same for a very thin tunnel. So, by definition of divergence, it is still $-4\pi G\rho$, where $\rho$ is the density of the sphere.

And if $\rho$ is the density of the sphere, it is not the density at $P$ because $P$ is supposed inside the tunnel, where $\rho = 0$.

What seems to happen is: the divergence of the field is not zero around $P$, so there are 'sources' for the vector field there. But that sources are not masses inside the small neighbourhood around $P$. They come from masses of the whole sphere. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking.  In particular, why do you need to invoke the tunnel in your question?  You could say the same thing about a point $P$ well outside the sphere;  you have $\rho = 0$ at $P$ but $\mathbf{g} \neq 0$, and the latter fact is due to sources that are not anywhere near $P$.

Comment: Density zero at x only means divergence zero for g (incompressible vector field), not that the source of the field g comes from the mass at x.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert if the point is outside the sphere, the field is $\mathbf g = -\frac{GM\mathbf{\hat r}}{r^2}$. It is easy to show that the divergence is zero in this case. What matches well with $\rho = 0$. The issue inside the tunnel is that $\rho = 0$ locally, but the divergence is not zero.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini I think that you are right. But in this case what is the meaning of $\rho$ in the formula: $\nabla \cdot \mathbf g = 4\pi G\rho$? Certainly it is not $\rho(P)$ because it is zero.

Comment: yes, $\rho(P)$ is zero, and also $\nabla \cdot \mathbf g(P) = 0$, however $\mathbf g(P)\ne 0$

Comment: @PatoGalmarini No. For P inside the tunnel, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf g(P) = -4\pi G\rho$, where $\rho$ is the density of the sphere.

Comment: yes, and didnt you agree that $\rho=0$ inside the tunnel? Why do you insist that it is the density of the sphere? I agree that g will be almost unchanged, but its divergence will change noticeably.

Comment: You are mixing the value of a function with that of its derivative.

Comment: Your expression for $\mathbf{g}$ assumes there is no tunnel. Of course, when you dig out the tunnel, you modify $\mathbf{g}$ so that it has no divergence in the tunnel. What's the problem?

Comment: Of course, the change in $\mathbf{g}$ is relatively small, but that doesn't mean the change in $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{g}$ also has to be small, because in the original configuration (a solid sphere), $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{g}$ is of order $g/r$ which is incredibly tiny, if $r$ is comparable to the radius of the Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider only the volume of the tunnel filled with mass density $\rho$, with no mass anywhere else. The resulting field is $\mathbf h$, with divergence $-4\pi G\rho$ inside "the tunnel".

Now consider the sphere with a tunnel drilled through it, and let $\mathbf g$ be the resulting field. Since $\mathbf g + \mathbf h$ must be the field for the whole sphere,

$$\mathbf g = -\frac{4}{3}\pi G\rho \mathbf r -\mathbf h $$

where $\mathbf h$ is the error in your approximation caused by neglecting the void in the tunnel. While $\mathbf h$ is small compared to $\mathbf g$, it has non-zero divergence in the tunnel, which ensures $\mathbf \nabla \cdot \mathbf g=0$ in the tunnel as required by Gauss' law.

Comment: If instead of a tunnel there a spherical void inside the sphere, the situation is more clear because the assumption of $-4\pi G\rho$ for the divergence of the little sphere can be proved from its field obtained by integration. I have an idea to prove that the rod has the same constant divergence even without knowing its field, but not sure yet.